# Go test does not find package tests in Makefile

Tags: makefile, go

I have following Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

boot:
    @go run main.go

test:
    @go test ./...

test-conf:
    @go test --verbose conf

test-httpd:
    @go test --verbose ./httpd

.PHONY: test test-conf test-httpd
```

Strangely enough `make test` works without problems however `make test-conf` or `make test-httpd` will both result in "github.com/bodokaiser/foobar [no test files]".

When I run `go test ./conf` from the working dir it works - shouldn't the makefile work too then?

**What do I need to do to get go test working with packages in a Makefile?**

PS: *I would like to avoid using $(pwd) or something in front of all paths if possible...*

Comment: The go tool works on packages, not files or directories (well, most of the time). Try using the whole (import)name of your package.

Comment: @Volker is there truly no relative way? I mean it works in the shell with "./conf"?

Comment: @Volker you must now I rename quite often :D

Comment: See: http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages . Relative import path work but are considered bad practice.  Testing the package in the current working directory is done normaly by running `go test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test-httpd` and `test-conf` don't work, as you can't use `--verbose` with `go test`, only `-v`.

Comment: Haha sometimes things can be so simple. Thank you!!

Comment: I had to try it myself, I use a Makefile myself and couldn't spot the error... you're welcome